# What does the gray exclamation mark means in Xcode 8.3?

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

I updated the Xcode to 8.3 version today, but I found a new error message, a gray exclamation mark. I do not know what it means, But the program can run normally. Does anyone know what this symbol means?

[image: this is the error pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error style is not new to Xcode 8.3, but your project may be experiencing new warnings or errors due to changes in Xcode 8.3 which is causing this style to appear.

That style is used to provide you with additional information about a given error or warning. You should see the primary issue somewhere above the grey exclamation mark style. There should also be a disclosure triangle that will let you collapse this additional information.

You need to resolve the primary issue.

Comment: If you need help resolving the primary issue, please post the full message.